# Issue with Step "block this step until steps finish" in PDI

Tags: kettle, pdi

While using Step "block this step until steps finish" in PDI Job will stop functioning after execution of 10k rows. How it can be solved?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue go to settings(double click on transformation where u r using this step),go to Miscellaneous in option "Nr of rows in rowset" there will be number 10000,this stops/blocks ur job execution replace that number whatever u want and run the job.